# ¿Cómo guardar el nuevo nodo en TreeView? C# y Windows Forms

Tags: c#, windows-forms, datatable, nodos

Tengo un *TreeView* con un función recursiva llamada `crearnodospadres`. Esta función me llama a una tabla en *SQL* que tiene los siguientes datos:

```
idpcuentas int autonumerico;
nombre,
codigo, 
idpadre
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero crear un botón de *agregar nuevo nodo* y se me agregue el *nodo hijo* debajo del que tengo seleccionado. Leí que es con el `selectednode.tag`, pero no sé cómo usarlo.

Tengo seleccionado `efectivo y equivalente`. ¿Cómo agarro el `idpcuentas` que en mi base de datos es *8* y ese *8* se le asigne al `idpadre` para que al crear el *nuevo nodo*, la base de datos sepa que es *hijo* de `efectivo` y equivalente y se cree debajo de este?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Llamo el `select` desde mi capa datos con un *DataTable*, uso programación en 3 capas.

Mi funcion recursiva:

```
private void CrearNodosPadre(int indicePadre, TreeNode nodePadre)
{
    DataTable dataTableNodos = new DataTable();
    dataTableNodos = planCuentas.RecogerDatos();

    DataView dataViewNodosHijos = new DataView(dataTableNodos);
    dataViewNodosHijos.RowFilter = dataTableNodos.Columns["IdPadre"].ColumnName + " = " + indicePadre;

    foreach (DataRowView dataFilas in dataViewNodosHijos)
    {
        TreeNode nuevoNodo = new TreeNode();
        nuevoNodo.Text = dataFilas["Nombre"].ToString().Trim();

        if (nodePadre == null)
        {
            treeView1.Nodes.Add(nuevoNodo);
        }
        else
        {
            nodePadre.Nodes.Add(nuevoNodo);
        }
        CrearNodosPadre(Int32.Parse(dataFilas["IdPCuentas"].ToString()), nuevoNodo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Estimada, bienvenida a StackOverflow en Español, te dejo de lectura obligatoria el [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) dado que falta ejemplificar código(lo que haz intentado para desarrollar tu problema) y un ejemplo de tu resultado esperado. Estoy atento al cambio de antecedentes para ayudarte.

Comment: Ya fue corregida la pregunta, espero pueda ayudarme

Comment: No me queda claro para que preguntas si  `nodePadre` es  `null` porque veo que haces exactamente lo mismo en ambos casos, a ver si me queda claro, lo que deseas es: *Buscar el `IdPcuentas` de cualquier nodo que selecciones, y ese id insertarlo como padre, cuando crees un nuevo nodo?* Si esto es correcto, avisame para formular una respuesta

Comment: si, efectivamente quiero eso, logré hacer que al apretar `guardar` y seleccionar el nodo se me guardara en la vista, pero no se me guarda en la base de datos lo hice con esto `padre = int.Parse(dataTableNodos.Rows[int.Parse(nodoSeleccionado.Tag.ToString())]["IdPCuentas"].ToString());`

Answer (score 0):

Está Ud. bien encaminado con el tema de la propiedad TAG. Su uso es muy versátil. Intentaré explicarle. En el ejemplo que le muestro se carga un treeview recursivamente, de categorías en este caso.

```
private void GetCategories()
    {
        treeCategories.Nodes.Clear();

        List<accountcategories> _mycats = _marketbusiness.getAllCategories();

        //rellenamos el tree view
        foreach (accountcategories _cat in _mycats.Where(c => c.CategoriaPadre == null))
        {
            List<TreeNode> _hijos = new List<TreeNode>();

            foreach (accountcategories _catsub in _mycats.Where(c => c.CategoriaPadre != null && c.CategoriaPadre.idCategoria == _cat.idCategoria))
            {
                TreeNode _hijo = new TreeNode(_catsub.Categoria);
                _hijo.Tag = _catsub;

                _hijos.Add(_hijo);
            }

            TreeNode _trprincipal = new TreeNode(_cat.Categoria, _hijos.ToArray());

            _trprincipal.Tag = _cat;

            treeCategories.Nodes.Add(_trprincipal);
        };

        treeCategories.ExpandAll();
    }
```

En el ejemplo uso una lista de objetos List para recorrer y asociar a cada nodo. Y cada elemento lo asocio a la propiedad TAG que después podré recuperar , por ejemplo en el AfterSelect

```
private void treeCategories_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        if (treeCategories.SelectedNode != null)
        {
            accountcategories _catsel = (accountcategories)treeCategories.SelectedNode.Tag;

            lblPalabrasClave.Text = _catsel.Categoria;

            GetPalabrasClave(_catsel.idCategoria);
        }
    }
```

Usted en lugar de una List<> está usando un dataTable. ¡No importa! En la propiedad TAG puede Ud. guardar lo que quiera, un valor individual, como por ejemplo el ID, la ROW del Datatable, lo que quiera; simplemente Ud deberá, al recuperar la propiedad TAG, usar el mismo tipo de dato que usó al informar el valor:

```
accountcategories _catsel = (**accountcategories**)treeCategories.SelectedNode.Tag;
```

Por favor, déjeme saber si le he ayudado